# window.open returns null when opening a webpage in my extension

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm working on a webextension for firefox, and used window.open to open a report page. Here is my code:

```
var reportURL = browser.extension.getURL("pages/report.html");
console.log(reportURL);
var myWindow = window.open(reportURL);
console.log("window.document");
console.log(myWindow);
```

The window is successfully opened, but myWindow is still null. I'm wondering why this is so. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is Firefox limitation, caused by the fact that the extension page and the opened window running in different browser processes. See [bug 1466347](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1466347#c4).